# How to print spawn_id in tcl expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I tried to print `spawn_id`, but it's not working:

```
puts $expect_out(spawn_id)
```

Could any one please direct me here? Thanks.

Comment: You want to just print it out to the console?

Answer (score 2):

After you `spawn`, you can access the `spawn_id` as `$spawn_id`.

So it's as simple as:

```
puts "$spawn_id"
```

Comment: is there some trick to using this to pass around a telnet instance?